# Calling a function from inside a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

If I have a threaded function, and from inside it I call another function (that is located in a separate .c file), does each instance of the threaded function get it's own version of the called function? Example:

### file 1

```
void* threaded_func(void* data) {
  function2(...);
}
```

### file 2

```
int a;

int function2(...) {
  int b;
}
```

In my example, would int a be the same int a for all threads? What about for variables I define inside function2 (i.e int b)?

Some context:

I'm creating a simple HTTP server and my function2 is a serve_client function which should only return when the connection is closed. I'm having a problem that I think is due to some variables in file2 (int a) being overwritten for each new thread. I think my problem is me expecting a C source file to behave like a class would in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does each instance of the threaded function get it's own version of the called function?

Loosely speaking, that's correct, provided the function doesn't use any global variables (e.g., `int a;` in your example) or any variable with static storage duration. If `a` is "shared" by multiple threads, that's likely to the source of your problem.

If `a` needs to be shared among threads, then you need to synchronize its access. If you `a` needs to be unique to each of threads, you need thread local storage. E.g., using C11's `__Thread_local` or gcc's [`__thread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html).

Answer (score 2):

A C function is just machine code, and could be run by several threads (or processes). What matters is the *data* used by that function. C don't have [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (you could emulate them with [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), that is  some function using additional client data). As [answered by usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867852/841108) read also about [thread local storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) with [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local). Each [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) has its own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

You should first read some [POSIX thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You need to care about [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) (and [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))), notably using [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) (and lock so [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability) access to global shared variables). Read also about [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transactions. Sometimes you can use [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) types and [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

BTW, you might want to use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

You should look into the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)).

On Linux, read also about [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), [nptl(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html) and [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) and [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).